# REACT env variables

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to setup a project for staging between dev to prod. I am trying to follow this article as it seems kind simple just to have a config file.
https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/manage-environments-in-create-react-app.html

However early in the article he states you set the variable by doing this:

```
REACT_APP_TEST_VAR=123 npm start
```

When i start by app like that I get following:
The term 'REACT_APP_STAGE=123' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function. Any pointers?

I also tried:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put the "REACT_APP_TEST_VAR=123" inside the script of npm start. For example when I run a npm build command it runs the following command (Where ENVIRONMENT is a env variable):

```
ENVIRONMENT=production webpack --mode production
```

So let's assume your cnpm start runs the regular "react-scripts start". You should define in your package json that the script "start" will do "REACT_APP_TEST_VAR=123 react-scripts start":

```
"start": "REACT_APP_TEST_VAR=123 react-scripts start",
```

Comment: I tried that too.  "scripts": {
    "start": "REACT_APP_TEST_VAR=123 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },. But getting same error: 'REACT_APP_TEST_VAR' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ibanform@0.1.0 start: `REACT_APP_TEST_VAR=123 react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1

Comment: It seems that you are inside windows. The correct command for batch would be `SET REACT_APP_TEST_VAR=123`. You can add `&&` operator to execute `react-scripts start` together, like `SET REACT_APP_TEST_VAR=123 && react-scripts start`. Not sure if this would work

Comment: Your right I am on windows. And you are also right in the approach as it worked. Thanks a lot appreciated!